# Magento 2.2.4 : Cart Subtotal, Shipping, Tax and Order Total not showing on checkout order summary section

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento2.2.4

I have the latest version (Magento 2.2.4) for my website.

There is a problem with checkout order summary.

Cart Subtotal, Shipping, Tax, and Order Total not showing on the checkout order summary section.

**Any idea what's the error?**

I have checked with **Luma** theme and also applied all basics operations (deploy, reindex, cache clear, etc).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Hard for us to check. Please, provide more info.

Comment: Is is a fresh version or not? Is there any browser error?

Comment: Yes its fresh Magento version. there is no any browser error.

check this screenshot : https://prnt.sc/jmcvl4

Comment: Check console log.

Comment: add shipping address and other details, after that you'll see summery.http://prntscr.com/jmd3th